# Using IP to detect Longitude and Latitude PHP

Tags: php

How is it possible to track ones location using IP Address using php or javascript?
Something like this website achieved: http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/216.157.85.163

Comment: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite You're getting "F" mark for using google skills

Comment: Just as long as you don care if the result is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very possible, both using PHP or JavaScript. However, there are ways to do it, and ways to not do it. Just like anything in life, really.

### JavaScript

If your browser has the `navigator.geolocation` object being in existence, it is able to get a location through either GPS or crowd-sourced wifi data. The object properties and methods are described in quite a bit of detail on the [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.navigator.geolocation).

The obvious advantage of this method is that the user's **device** will give back the geolocation, **NOT** the IP address of the visitor. This means that this is able to tunnel through proxies, TOR etc. This will, however, prompt the user for the location - and it rightfully does so, imagine the chaos otherwise.

To use it:

```
 if (navigator.geolocation && navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      }, function() { alert("Couldn't get your position!"); });
 }
```

`position` will contain a Position object, whose coordinates are in `coords`.

### PHP, JavaScript etc: through an API

There are many APIs to do the requests for you. You should investigate a couple - Google provides a geolocation API, there's also [ipinfodb](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api_json.php)... Some have a cap on requests, some don't. 
They work by IP, however. Which means no proxy tunnelling and approximate location.

Comment: Yup, it is what I'm finding for, however, when it says that there is a lag between APIs. Is there anyway possible to setup my own database

Comment: @user288231: The trade-off in doing so is between having to maintain your database. IP blocks get reallocated every day. If you don't mind doing this, setting it up locally is your best bet. Note that all the free DBs are inaccurate - you're better off paying $100/year for a subscription to a *good* DB.

Comment: Do you then know where I could purchase a subscription of a MySQL db?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access a GeoLocation database, send it to the IP and it will return the cordinates and/or the city name of the IP.

You can check into this API to get started: http://freegeoip.net/

or, get the data here to run your own: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite

or, use Google's API to locate users based on cell towers: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/